# Fetch data from slider at onDragEnd when state is being mutated in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a slider that changes the values of a state variable:

```
onChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({sliderValue: value,});
};

onDragEnd = (event, value) => {
    this.props.fetchData(value);
};


...


<Slider
   value={this.state.sliderValue}
   min={0}
   max={100}
   step={1}
   onChange={(event, value) => this.onChange(event, value)}
   onDragEnd={(event) => this.onDragEnd(event)}
/>
```

Sometimes, to setState for *this.state.sliderValue* takes some time and this.props.fetchData(value)* gets fired before so the data fetch is being made with an old value.

How can I assure, that the last value of this.state.sliderValue is being fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve the problem with RxJS debounceTime operator:

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs";
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

let onChange$ = new Subject();

...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getWeightedCriteria(this.props.decisionId);

        const subscription = onChange$
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500)
            )
            .subscribe(
                data => this.fetchSliderValues(data)
            );

        // prevent memory leaks
        this.setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, subscription}));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // prevent memory leaks
        this.state.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    onChange = (event, value) => {
        onChange$.next(value);
    };

...
```

With the debounceTime operator, values are fetched after the values don't change for 500 ms. Then the DragEnd method is not needed anymore.

*After I got some experience with react, I learned that you should never trust components firing events with a specific order.*

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

**The state update is an asynchronous task**. So you are updating `sliderValue` when the slider changes its value, then you set the state `sliderValue` to the slider to update its value, but can occur that the state is not updated when you stop dragging the slider and you `onDragEnd` callback is notified with the old value.

Solution:

In the function, `onDragEnd` just mark that the data must be retrieved. The value you need for performing the `fetch` is the state so it is not needed the value returned by the slider.

Then you can use `componentDidUpdate` to fetch the data.

code example:

```
onChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({sliderValue: value,});
};


componentDidUpdate(prevPros, prevState) {
  // if data must be fetched and my slider value is updated (prev and current match)
  if (this.state.fetchDataEnabled && prevState.sliderValue === this.state.sliderValue) {
    this.props.fetchData(this.state.sliderValue);
    this.setState({fetchDataEnabled: false});
  }
}


<Slider
   value={this.state.sliderValue}
   min={0}
   max={100}
   step={1}
   onChange={(event, value) => this.onChange(event, value)}
   onDragEnd={() => this.setState({fetchDataEnabled: true})}
/>
```

Comment: I just tested, but it is still happening. If this.setState({fetchDataEnabled: false}); is happening before this.state.sliderValue mutates, an old value is being send :(

Comment: how? I can't see the race condition

Comment: I think [here](https://1drv.ms/p/s!Aj5iyhlekI34jcsP2D7y3xt5NOx7Jg) you can see where the problem is

Comment: I was assuming that onDragEnd is fired after onChange. So You mean that an onchange event can occur after you stop dragging?

Comment: I fixed a typo it was not  `this.prevState` is `prevState` without `this`

Comment: The onDragEnd is being always fired after onChange. But the state mutation in onChange takes longer as in onDragEnd because the sliderValue is in reality a big array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193127/discussion-between-f-bernal-and-jocker).